# Adjust the header height in wordpress website

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

This the [website](https://www.teststage.abayaclick.com) i am currently working.The header looks good in desktop but in mobile I see the height of the header is so high.How I can change the header height only in mobile.Is there any CSS I can add to my 'Additional CSS' tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add css tot the 'Additional CSS' tab. Use a media query to address only mobile. Then you probably want to remove some space around the logo. You can do that by altering the top and bottom padding:

```
 @media (max-width: 767px) {
     .header-branding-wrap {
          padding: 5px 15px;
     }
 }
```